# .env file I need to be a string

Tags: node.js, string, api, dotenv

I have an api request for a spotify app I am doing with Nodejs.

I am trying to place the API keys in a .env file and call from the main app.js

I'm calling them in the app with a querystring

I'm new to programming and am trying to figure out how I can do this.

I've tried converting the file .toString() but I get a type error

when I do a typeOf of the variable I get 'undefined'

is there a way to convert the variable to a query string while keeping my api keys in the .env file?

```
require('dotenv').config();

var client_id = process.env.CLIENT_.toString(); // Your client id
console.log(client_id);
var client_secret = process.env.CLIENT_S; // Your secret
```

When I try to do it without this I get the error:  "Missing required parameter: client_id"

```
var client_id = process.env.CLIENT_; // Your client id, i want to be a string
console.log(client_id); //client id comes up undefined
var client_secret = process.env.CLIENT_S; // Your secret
```

I have dotenv installed as it's appearing in my package.json file as:

```
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
```

In my .env file my client keys look like:

```
 CLIENT_=61011 //Example key
 CLIENT_S=0f798//Example key
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you load the .env file with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

Comment: Can you share the file `.env`?

Comment: I loaded the dotenv file with npm install dotenv and have require('dotenv').config(); int the file

Comment: I can't share the .env file as it has my API keys in it that I am trying to hide but the structure is:  CLIENT_= abcde CLIENT_S=abcde

Comment: wrap your key values in single quotes, sometimes if there are special characters funky things can happen in the .env file.   also make sure you installed npm dotenv to the right directory

Comment: Hi, I tried putting it in single quotes and it still didn't work. I've added more code and an example of my .env file. Hoping this helps. Thanks so much for trying to help me.

Comment: try first to get a normal env variable working, like: 
TEST="this is a test"
Then once you succeed to read it from a console log in your code, move forward and do it for your api key. Then change it to a string.
Best

Comment: I fixed it thank you so much for all of your help. I appreciate it so much!!!

Comment: If you fixed it, could you please add your solution, I'm having the same issue with hexadecimal values (ethereum contract addresses). For me the solution was to wrap the whole value with single quotes after double quotes: CONTRACT_ADDRESS='"0x123"'